# How to get next key in an array from given key in php?

Tags: php, arrays

For example i have an array with the element of following

```
$array = array(
               1 => "a",
               3 => "c",
               4 => "d",
               6 => "f",
              );
```

how could i get next key from given key, if I'm using some function like

```
get_next_key_array($array,1);
it should return 3.
```

if it be

```
 get_next_key_array($array,4);
 it should return 6.
```

Is it can be done, I know that next(),current(),prev() in php, but i don't know how to implement my required result using default functions.
Please help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Try this out**

```
function get_next_key_array($array,$key){
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    $position = array_search($key, $keys);
    if (isset($keys[$position + 1])) {
        $nextKey = $keys[$position + 1];
    }
    return $nextKey;
}
```

Comment: This one is still a lifesaver and a keeper. Add '- 1' into a new function and you have all your prev-next-buttons working on every array you can come up with.

Comment: A good IDE will inform you that `$nextKey` might not be declared at the `return` line.  Maybe it should be `return $keys[$position + 1] ?? null;` instead of the `if`+`return`.  This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
function get_next_key_array( $array, $find_key ) {
    $flag = false;
    foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
        if( $flag ) {
            return $key;
        }
        if( $key === $find_key ) {
            $flag = true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$len = count($array);
$keys = array_keys($array);
$keys_map = array_flip($keys);
if($keys_map[$current_key]>=$len-1)
    $nextkey = $keys[0];
else
    $nextkey = $keys[$keys_map[$current_key]];
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is done for normal case:

```
function get_next_key_array(&$array, $key)
{
    while (key($array) !== $key) {
        next($array);
    }
    next($array);

    return key($array);
}
$array = array(
    1 => 'a',
    3 => 'c',
    4 => 'd',
    6 => 'f',
);
$key = 4;
echo get_next_key_array($array, $key);
```

**[DEMO](http://phpio.net/s/2t61)**

Comment: Note that if the key is not detected, you go in an infinite loop.

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.